# How to get the last createdAt item with TypeORM

Tags: postman, nestjs, typeorm

Hi friends I need help with this query that I want to make to return only the last 'Case' by 'User'.

On my PostMan request I have my service that returns all the cases that the user have made.

users.services.ts

```
  async findCasesbyUserId(id: number) {
    return await this.usersRepository.findOne(id, { relations: ['cases']})
  }
```

users.controller.ts

```
  @Get('/findCase/:id')
  async findCasesByUserId(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number,) {
    return this.usersService.findCasesbyUserId(id)
  }
```

When I made my GET request to 'http://localhost:3000/users/findCase/3'. This is the result that I get.

The user with id=3 have the cases with the id=1, id=2, id=3

So I want only to return only the case with the id=3 because is the last created case. I need a way to get the last case by the field createdAt or another way could be great for me.

Im using NestJs with TypeORM for thew querys to my PostgreSQL DB.

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "createdAt": "1617983079621",
    "updatedAt": "1617983079621",
    "name": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "email": "jdoe@email.com",
    "username": "JohnDoe",
    "password": "**************",
    "role": "Admin",
    "isActive": true,
    "document": "12345",
    "address": "Test",
    "phone": "12345",
    "cases": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "createdAt": "1618504530817",
            "updatedAt": "1618504530817",
            "message": "Test Case 1",
        },
                {
            "id": 2,
            "createdAt": "1618504530817",
            "updatedAt": "1618504530817",
            "message": "Test Case 1",
        },        {
            "id": 3,
            "createdAt": "1618546146772",
            "updatedAt": "1618546146772",
            "message": "Test Case 1",
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: does the `id` refer to the case ID or the user ID?

Comment: If id in cases is a number you can simply return the largest one and would not need to compare dates.